# How to set up separate log and commit disks

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am very new to Cassandra and Red Hat Linux. I have been reading around and have learned enough to know that with spinning disks, it is wise to separate the commit and data storage onto two separate disks. That said, I don't actually know how to do this. Could one of you more experienced gurus provide me some instructions?  I have the following drives:
Disk 1 - commit log: /dev/sda3
Disk 2 - data storage: /dev/sdb

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I figured it out. Mount the drives and change the yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above for a rough version of the solution.